# Split string in multiple string with a condition

Tags: python

the following code takes a string as input and split it in a list of string everytime the current letter is a consonant and next letter is a vowel. It is quite slow, how can I improve it? Thank you

```
def count_syllables(word):
    word= list(word)
    vowels= {"a":1,"e":2,"i":3,"o":4,"u":5,"y":6,"j":7}
    s = word[0]
    syllables = [ ]
    count = 1
    l_max = len(word)
    while count != l_max :
        if word[count] not in vowels and word[count-1] in vowels:
            syllables.append(s)
            s = word[count]
            count += 1
        else:
            s += word[count]
            count += 1
    syllables.append(s)

    value1 = len(syllables)
    value2 = syllables[-1]
    return (value1, value2)
```

Comment: Its seems that the complexity is O(len(word)), why do you consider it slow ?
You need anyway to pass through the whole word to find all the syllables.

Comment: This is only a part of exercise where the timeout is 100ms and just this part takes +- 67ms to execute (I pass inside it multiple string in a list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
def count_syl(word:str):
    vowels = set("eyuioa")
    syllables = []
    count = 0
    i = 0
    while i < len(word) - 1:
        if word[i] in vowels and word[i + 1] not in vowels:
            syb = word[count:i+1]
            count = i + 1
            syllables.append(syb)
        i += 1
    syllables.append(word[count:])
    return (len(syllables), syllables)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use regular expressions

```
import re

def count_syllables(word):
    syllables = re.findall("[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxy]+[aeiouy]*", word)
    return len(syllables), syllables
```

Comment: Thank you! Forgot to mention that i can't import anything, sorry!